# What are the hardware requirements for performing native compilation in a Gitlab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab-ci, quarkus, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to set up continuous integration for a Quarkus project with native compilation, and the technology department is asking me for the hardware requirements.

Would anyone know what the hardware requirements are for a GitLab runner?

Considering that the native compilation of a Quarkus project requires a heavy load of resources for this task, I'm looking for the hardware requirements, but I'm not finding them when I search online.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6531#issuecomment-1578905484

Comment: Thank you @geoand for the information. What I need is the GitLab Runner configuration, how many processors and how much memory RAM are necessary to be able to perform native compilation. Anyone knows?

Comment: @LuisMoyano this answer state that 6go is enough https://stackoverflow.com/a/63111798/12176221, but honestly i've seen some others with 8go throwing OOM.
IMHO you should consider at least 8go, and go up if needed. As for CPU, never had any problem with 2, but this mainly define compilation speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It depends on how many time you are willing to wait

For a few month now, i've been running native compilation via default Gitlab shared runners and it's fine.

I use it on fairly large Quarkus projects, and it is taking 20 to 25 minutes per native artifact (with default configuration).

FYI, I'm using default `saas-linux-small-amd64` runners, which according to documentation is 2CPUs and 8GB ram. See [Gitlab shared Runner specs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html#machine-types-available-for-linux-x86-64)

You could easily use shared runners to narrow down which one works best for you (and your project needs), and then use similar hardware.
The default one cost almost nothing, but is long to run. Picking the best one will result in huge costs and shorter run time.

And last but not least, don't forget that increasing runner specs will also increase cost ratio. So if you want to keep free plan and increase runner specs, you will at least double your compute minute cost. Some of the best runners are even Premium only.
See [Compute quotas](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/cicd_minutes.html#additional-costs-on-gitlab-saas)